# Openshift Pod Storage Mongodb - Download the volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, openshift

I'm new in Openshift and I have a Pod with a mongodb inside and a Volume which is the mongo's dbpath.

Now for a reason that I don't understand my pod is not working anymore and the only message that I get is: **Waiting for MongoDB daemon up**

Since I'm new in Openshift and Docker, I would like to try download the volume of my pod(which is the same as a Container right?) and try to debug locally(my machine) using Docker to create a new container with that volume attached.

The hardest part until now is realize how download the Volume of my pods in my machine.
I checked the command PVC:

```
$ oc get pvc
mymongodb             1y29d
mymongodb-shop         370d
```

I would like to download the mymongodb volume. How could be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an access to actual storage, you can always use `oc debug` to create a debug pod with `/bin/sh` shell to see what's wrong. If you still want to copy data to your PC, you may open debug pod in one terminal window, and then copy data from it to your PC from another window.

Assuming you have a statefulset named **mongodb**, you should run

`oc debug statefulset/mongodb`

Which will create a pod named **mongodb-debug**

After that you can copy any folder you need using following command in another terminal window

`oc cp mongodb-debug:/your_directory_on_pod /your_local_dir`

You may also use `oc rsync` instead of `oc cp` if your pod supports it.

Then close a first terminal and debug pod will be automatically deleted

To learn more about `oc debug`: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#debug